# How to remove from starting and from end of string after certain characters?

Tags: php, arrays, string, character, substr

I have this: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/website/inn/hemlata993/93/`

I want to remove `/opt/lampp/htdocs` and the `/` at the end so eveyrthing after the  2nd `/` at the  end should get removed. In the above example `/93` should get removed  hence it would be:

`/website/inn/hemlata993/`

I tried doing this:

```
$files = glob($dirName."*.*");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    echo $image;
    $arr = explode('/opt/lampp/htdocs', $image);
    $important = $arr[1];
 
    echo '<img src="'.$important.'" width="100" height="100" alt="Random image" />' . "<br /><br />";

}
```

This removes `/opt/lampp/htdocs` I was wondering how do I remove the end one as well, and store it in one variable? I try using substr, but after removing the first part its storing in array I assume so I am not able to do that. How can I get `/website/inn/hemlata993/`?

Comment: `93` is not "after the `/` at the end"...

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2nd `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use a regex to match everything after `/opt/lampp/htdocs` and up to and including the 2nd to last `/`. For example:

```
$image = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/website/inn/hemlata993/93/';
$image = preg_replace('#/opt/lampp/htdocs(/.*/)[^/]+/[^/]*$#', '$1', $image);
echo $image;
```

Output:

```
/website/inn/hemlata993/
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/cBfHT)

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Also I was wondering I have certain folders inside hemlata993 such as folder1, folder2 and so on and inside folder1 there are some images and same goes for folder 2 etc. How can I print all those folder images? Or shall I ask that as another question?

Comment: @ikea that sounds like you just need to `glob($image . '*/*.jpg')` or something similar

Comment: I have tried that it only works if there is only one folder inside the folder hemlata993

Comment: Might be easier to ask another question then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205527/how-to-post-images-on-website-from-my-folder?noredirect=1#comment111767326_63205527. Please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a solution that doesn't depend on your website's physical location:

```
$path = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/website/inn/hemlata993/93/';
if (preg_match('#/website/(.*)/(?=\d+/)#', $path, $matches)) {
  $path = $matches[0];
}
```

This, however, assumes that:

- `/website` is where the files are located within the server's document root,
- the paths always end with one or more digits at the end (before the last `/`).

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0DWL6)**